# Error al ejecutar proyecto de Android studio

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente error. Ejecuto el proyecto pero al momento de que intenta instalar el .apk en el teléfono indica error en instalación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sólo pulsa en "OK", no queda con eso?

Comment: Desintalla la aplicacion de tu emulador/dispositivo  y prueba otra vez.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo no queda fijate, al hacer ok, dice error al instalar apk.

Comment: @Einer no ha instalado la apk en ninguna ocasión.

Comment: haz clean project y vuelve a intentar compilarlo

Comment: @L.Ronquillo disculpa como hago eso, soy principiante en esto.?

Comment: En la barra de herramientas, esta el apartado de "project" (o algo similar, no recuerdo bien) y ahí está la opción de "clean project"

Comment: @L.Ronquillo gracias, me imagino eran algo de sincronización o cambios, ya me permitió ejecutar, ahora puedo seguir.

Comment: Lo que yo te aconsejo es que revises si tienes una app con el mismo nombre de paquete instalado y la desinstales, en caso de que no sea así, lo mejor es limpiar el proyecto(Clean Build) y volver a compilar

Answer (score 1):

**Esto no es un error en tu aplicación o de Android Studio**, es un aviso que indica que la instalación del .apk "fallo", porque se tiene una version de la aplicación que fue firmada con otro keystore, probablemente es una aplicación de la playstore o subida en otra pc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si aceptas simplemente permites eliminar la aplicación actual e instalar la que genero Android Studio.

---

**Si aceptas,  decides que la versión instalada sea eliminada y se instale la nueva, posteriormente tratas de realizarlo nuevamente, ya no se mostraría el mensaje ya que el .apk que intenta subir fue firmado con el mismo keystore que la que instalaste (en este caso el debug keystore).**

---

Como comentario extra: en el texto que indica el dialogo no se muestra la palabra "error".

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar la respuesta de @Jorgesys, no solo es que tenga diferente key la app instalada en el móvil, suele darse cuando cambias de flavors para compilación, en algunos casos, por cada flavor se maneja diferente key, y cuando se compila para debug, utiliza la key generada especialmente para ese flavor y si cambias para release, utilizará el key de ese flavor, solo ten cuidado a donde esta apuntando la url de conexión, así que dale con fé, el de desinstalar el app para que se instale el app que estas compilando.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me paso lo mismo cuando compile una app con el mismo nombre de otra ya instalada en el dispositivo o emulador.

La solución es desinstalar la app que causa el conflicto o limpiar la información del emulador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es necesario desinstalarla manualmente, de hecho es precisamente [lo que menciona el mensaje](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91430/95), solo hay que aceptar, se elimina la instalada y se instala el nuevo .apk.